# String manipulation using lodash chaining

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to change the string `"Showing  8,868      research       papers in XXX Journal;  published between 2000-01-01 and 2015-06-31"`

to:
 `New research papers in XXX Journal; published from 2001-01-01 onward`

I came up with the following code that uses lodash:

```
 var desc = _.chain($('.description').text())
    .thru(function (text) { return text.replace(/\s+/g, ' ') })
    .thru(function (text) { return text.replace(/Showing\s[\d+\,*]+/, 'New') })
    .split(';')
    .map(function (phrase) {return phrase.replace('between', 'from').replace(/and\s[\d+-.]+/, 'onward') })
    .join(';')
    .value()
```

But I always get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line `.thru(function (text) { return text.replace(/\s+/g, ' ') })`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which version of lodash are you using ? http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/W4QfJ/432/ it seems to be working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you use outdated version of lodash, since your code works with lodash 3.9.3. Note that `_.thru` is not implemented in lodash 2.*

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated to your `TypeError`, you could use [method()](https://lodash.com/docs#method) and [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs#flow) to make your code a lot smaller:

```
function replace(a, b) { return _.method('replace', a, b); }

_($('.description').text())
    .chain()
    .thru(replace(/\s+/g, ' '))
    .thru(replace(/Showing\s[\d+\,*]+/, 'New'))
    .split(';')
    .map(_.flow(replace('between', 'from'), replace(/and\s[\d+-.]+/, 'onward')))
    .join(';')
    .value()
```